# Best way to retrieve Redis list values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, redis

What is the most common way is to retrieve all values in a list when those values are relatively large serialised Ruby objects?

For example:

- I have 5000 values in a Redis list
- Each value in the list contains a 50K Ruby object serialised as a string

I need to iterate through all of these values in Ruby, is it more performant to:

1. Use `lrange` to get all the values in one trip, then iterate through them in Ruby
2. Use `llen` to count the values in the list, then loop through in Ruby using `lindex` to retrieve each value as an individual trip to Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, it makes no difference. Choose one that is easier to code for you. Any speed gains from using LRANGE will be dominated by time needed to transfer your large objects. I would probably process them one by one, this way it uses less memory.